# in math-mode, underline adjacent variables, except with space between underlines

Tags: math-mode

In mathmode, is there a way to underline a veriable that doesn't make the underline join to the next variable?  Example:

```
\underline{X}\underline{Y}
```

except I want a break in the underline between X and Y.

the way i'm doing it now is comersome:

```
\text{ }\underline{X}\text{ }\underline{Y}
```

would be nice if there were a way to get an underline that is shorter and centers on the character so i doesn't bleed to the edge of the next character. because I'm trying to write matrix equations that have many vector variables marked with underlines...

Comment: `\underline{X}\,\underline{Y}`. But do you really need underlining? That was used when typewriters had very limited features.

Comment: yes because I can't use \vec{X} in the matrix equations because its too ugly and messy... thus, I want to move the bar below the variable and remove the arrow... it i don't mark them as vectors then it gets confusing to distinguish between scalars and vectors....and I can't use bold face either because my eyes can't see bold face vs. normal characters....

Comment: I'd use `\mathbf{v}` or  `\bm{v}` for vectors.

Comment: sorru, can't use that... its too hard for me to read bold face verse normal text...

Comment: ```\underbar{X}\underbar{Y}``` except it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 4):

Underlining is ugly. You can somehow mitigate it by shortening the underline:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{%
  \mspace{2mu}%
  \underline{\mspace{-2mu}#1\mspace{-2mu}}%
  \mspace{2mu}%
}

\begin{document}

$\alpha\vec{X}\vec{Y}$

$\alpha XY$

\end{document}
```

The second line is for comparison.

[image]

Another strategy could be using `accents`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\alpha\vec{X}\vec{Y}$

$\alpha XY$

\end{document}
```

[image]

My preference would go to `\bm`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\alpha\vec{X}\vec{Y}$

$\alpha XY$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case use proper markup. You might not want to redefine `\vec` and use a different command name. This way, you can change the appearance of all vectors by just changing the definition.